# Validar usuarios con PHP y MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Ya he visto muchos posts acerca de mi problema y no logro que verifique el usuario y contrasena de la base de datos. Soy nuevo en esto y agradeceria su ayuda, gracias.

```php
$dbhost='localhost';
$dbport='5432';
$dbname='webcar';
$dbusr='cabada';
$dbpasw='mysql';
$dbcon= mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbusr,$dbpasw,$dbname);
$usuario= $_POST['usuario'];
$contrasena= $_POST['contra'];
$contra_encr = md5($contrasena);

$consulta = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbcon, "select * from usuarios where nombre_usuario = '$usuario' and password_usuario = '$contra_encr'"));

echo "Hola";

if($consulta==0)
    echo "Usuario invalido, por favor de indentificarse..";
else {
    header("Location:WebCar.html");
    echo "Si se pudo";
    exit;
}

?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo que en lugar de agregar una imagen de tu código, agregues el código como tal, para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida.

Comment: Tu código está mal implementado. Por favor cambia la imagen por el texto del código para poder reproducirlo y decirte cómo tienes que corregir el programa. Para estos casos la imágenes no ayudan en nada, si alguien quiere ayudarte tendría que estar mirando la imagen y copiando tu código. Pulsa en [edit] para poner el texto del código. Gracias.

Comment: Has la condición al revés y en lugar de 0 coloca `if $consulta>1`

Comment: Hola un par de sugerencias: 1.- No uses md5 para encriptar, está obsoleto y es muy fácil de decifrar [ https://md5online.es/ ] 2.- No necesitas traer todos los campos de la tabla "usuarios" basta con traer un solo campo para saber si esta validado o no (Estás trayendo también el usuario y la contraseña y como el código que estás usando está muy expuesto a inyecciones sql sería muy fácil  obtener esos datos) 3.- Para evitar los ultimo te sugiero interiorizarse en conexiones con PDO con  marcadores de posición. Te dejo un vinculo a una cosnulta de este mismo sitio: http://tiny.cc/167s5y

Comment: Como comenta @EduardoMunizaga, `md5` no es seguro, deberías usar `password_hash` y `password_verify` e implementar consultas preparadas. Aunque si quieres saber por qué no funciona este código, puedes en primer lugar hacer una comprobación de los resultados, por cierto, evita mezclas de llamadas como: `$consulta = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($dbcon, "select *...));` Más bien, saca los resultados aparte: `$rs=mysqli_query($dbcon, "select *...);` así podrás probar si la consulta trae datos `var_dump($rs);`  (esto es sólo para prueba). Y luego usas `$rs` para saber cuántas filas hay...

Comment: ... aunque aquí lo más óptimo y seguro sería lanzar una consulta del tipo `SELECT COUNT(*) ...`, no es bueno estar trayendo en el `SELECT` datos que no vas a usar, y mucho menos traer todos los datos del usuario, contraseña incluida.